# Indexed list creates problems for the list2env() function

Tags: r, dplyr

Via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71303245/transform-a-common-variable-within-a-series-of-datasets-without-placing-those-da) post I discovered the fascinating `list2env()` function in conjunction with `dplyr` lists, allowing the user to move the contents of a named list out into the global environment. However I have run into some problems, best illustrated by the example below.

Say we have a list of datasets

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = letters[1:6], y = rnorm(6))
df2 <- data.frame(x = letters[1:6], y = rnorm(6))
df3 <- data.frame(x = letters[1:6], y = rnorm(6))
```

Now say we want to apply a function to each, in this case transforming the character vector `x` to a factor. To do this we create a function.

```
factorFunct <- function(d) d %>% mutate(x = factor(x))
```

Now, using `dplyr::lst()` we can create a list containing all the datasets, and apply our function to each

```
library(dplyr)
dfList <- dplyr::lst(df1, df2, df3)
dfList <- lapply(dfList, function(i) factorFunct(i))
```

Now when we examine each dataset in the list our character vectors have been changed to factors.

```
glimpse(dfList[[2]])

# Rows: 6
# Columns: 2
# $ x <fct> a, b, c, d, e, f
# $ y <dbl> -0.5809778, 0.8465600, 0.1022410, -0.9117389, 1.0635876, 0.3148138
```

Now what is *really* cool is that, using the `list2env()` function, we can move the transformed datasets back out into the global environment

```
list2env(dfList, .GlobalEnv)
```

So that the original datasets themselves have *also* been transformed.

```
glimpse(df2)

# Rows: 6
# Columns: 2
# $ x <fct> a, b, c, d, e, f
# $ y <dbl> -0.5809778, 0.8465600, 0.1022410, -0.9117389, 1.0635876, 0.3148138
```

A small but important thing to note is that our list of datasets is *named*

```
names(dfList)

# [1] "df1" "df2" "df3"
```

So far so good. *My* issue is that I have tried to apply a different transformation function to the list, one that adds a prefix to a subset of the variables in each of the datasets. This function requires a list of prefixes be created

```
preList <- dplyr::lst(one = "one", two = "two", three = "three")
```

Now to create the function that adds the prefixes, using the `rename_with()` function from `dplyr`

```
renameCols <- function(d, prefix) d %>% rename_with(.fn = ~ paste0(prefix, .x), .cols = matches("x"))
```

Now, let's apply the function to the list of datasets we created above

```
dfList <- lapply(1:length(dfList), function(i) renameCols(dfList[[i]], preList[[i]]))
```

Within the list it has worked, the `x` variable has had a prefix added to it.

```
glimpse(dfList[[3]]) 

# Rows: 6
# Columns: 2
# $ threex <fct> a, b, c, d, e, f
# $ y      <dbl> 2.47582743, -0.04879153, -0.13771671, -0.41982932, -0.36765793, 0.21731860
```

However *this* time when we run the list2env function to move the transformed datasets back out into the global environment we get an error message

```
list2env(dfList, .GlobalEnv)

# Error in list2env(dfList, .GlobalEnv) : names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x
```

I think I know what is going on is that my function has stripped `dfList` of the names it needs to move each element of the list back out into the global environment

```
names(dfList)

# NULL
```

I suspect this is because I used a numerical index in the `lapply()` function rather than the list itself, but I do not know if this is truly the source of the problem, nor, even if it is, how to get the result I need.

Comment: Use `Map(renameCols, dfList, preList)` instead of `lapply()` with an index to preserve the names.

Comment: "Now what is really cool is that, using the list2env() function, we can move the transformed datasets back out into the global environment" No, that's not cool. It's bad practice. Don't clutter your global environment when you have these objects already nice and tidy in a list. `list2env` was not created to assign into the global environment.

Comment: @Roland I do not have a programming background. Could you explain *why* it is bad practice to move the transformed datasets back out into Global Environment?

Comment: Can you explain why you'd want to do that? What is the advantage over keeping them in the list (which offers advantages like being able to easily iterate over them). Do you put all your files just into `D:` or do use folders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is that your list of dataframes 'lost' their names after applying your renaming function; if you reassign the names your function works, e.g.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(x = letters[1:6], y = rnorm(6))
df2 <- data.frame(x = letters[1:6], y = rnorm(6))
df3 <- data.frame(x = letters[1:6], y = rnorm(6))

preList <- lst(one = "one", two = "two", three = "three")
dfList <- dplyr::lst(df1, df2, df3)

renameCols <- function(d, prefix) {
  d %>%
    rename_with(.fn = ~ paste0(prefix, .x),
                .cols = matches("x"))
}

dfList2 <- lapply(seq_along(dfList), function(i) {renameCols(d = dfList[[i]],
                                                             prefix = preList[[i]])})
names(dfList2)
#> NULL

names(dfList2) <- names(dfList)

list2env(dfList2, .GlobalEnv)
#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>

df1
#>   onex           y
#> 1    a -0.56047565
#> 2    b -0.23017749
#> 3    c  1.55870831
#> 4    d  0.07050839
#> 5    e  0.12928774
#> 6    f  1.71506499
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Edit

Here is an approach using purrr::map2

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(x = letters[1:6], y = rnorm(6))
df2 <- data.frame(x = letters[1:6], y = rnorm(6))
df3 <- data.frame(x = letters[1:6], y = rnorm(6))

preList <- lst(one = "one", two = "two", three = "three")
dfList <- lst(df1, df2, df3)

renameCols <- function(d, prefix) {
  d %>%
    rename_with(.fn = ~ paste0(prefix, .x),
                .cols = matches("x"))
}

#dfList2 <- lapply(seq_along(dfList), function(i) {renameCols(d = dfList[[i]],
#                                                             prefix = preList[[i]])})
#names(dfList2)
#
#names(dfList2) <- names(dfList)
#
#list2env(dfList2, .GlobalEnv)

#dfList3 <- Map(renameCols, dfList, preList)
#dfList3

library(purrr)
dfList4 <- map2(.x = dfList, .y = preList, .f = ~ renameCols(d = .x, prefix = .y))
dfList4
#> $df1
#>   onex           y
#> 1    a -0.56047565
#> 2    b -0.23017749
#> 3    c  1.55870831
#> 4    d  0.07050839
#> 5    e  0.12928774
#> 6    f  1.71506499
#> 
#> $df2
#>   twox          y
#> 1    a  0.4609162
#> 2    b -1.2650612
#> 3    c -0.6868529
#> 4    d -0.4456620
#> 5    e  1.2240818
#> 6    f  0.3598138
#> 
#> $df3
#>   threex          y
#> 1      a  0.4007715
#> 2      b  0.1106827
#> 3      c -0.5558411
#> 4      d  1.7869131
#> 5      e  0.4978505
#> 6      f -1.9666172

names(dfList4)
#> [1] "df1" "df2" "df3"
list2env(dfList4, .GlobalEnv)
#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
df1
#>   onex           y
#> 1    a -0.56047565
#> 2    b -0.23017749
#> 3    c  1.55870831
#> 4    d  0.07050839
#> 5    e  0.12928774
#> 6    f  1.71506499
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @jared_mamrot. Do you have any inkling *why* my second function stripped `dfList` of its names when the first function did not?

Comment: I don't think lapply is the correct 'tool' for this job; I think you want purrr::map or Map to preserve the df names. I have tried a few different approaches to retain the names with lapply but I haven't been able to come up with a solution, sorry

Comment: @llewmills - it's because the names are copied from the object passed to `lapply()`.  In your first use you passed it a named list and in the second an unnamed vector.

Comment: @jared_mamrot you've done more than enough to be awarded the answer, but I'd love to see the purrr::map solution.

Comment: Thanks @llewmills, I've edited my answer to show an example with purrr::map2 (not purrr::map sorry; you need to provide ".x" and ".y" for each 'renaming' which I believe requires purrr::map2)

Comment: NB @RitchieSacramento has the 'best' answer (in my opinion) in his comment with `Map(renameCols, dfList, preList)`, so if Ritchie posts that as an answer please accept that answer instead :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `mget` to avoid the temporary list, and the renaming problem virtually asks for using `Map`.

```
Map(\(x, y) 
    setNames(factorFunct(x), paste0(c(y, ''), names(df1))),
    mget(ls(pattern='^df\\d$')),
    preList) |> 
  list2env(.GlobalEnv)

df1
#   onex          y
# 1    a  1.3709584
# 2    b -0.5646982
# 3    c  0.3631284
# 4    d  0.6328626
# 5    e  0.4042683
# 6    f -0.1061245

str(df1)
# 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ onex: Factor w/ 6 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6
#  $ y   : num  1.371 -0.565 0.363 0.633 0.404 ...
```

**Note:** R >= 4.1 used.

In the function, instead of `dplyr::mutate` we alternatively could use `transform`.

```
factorFunct <- function(d) transform(d, x=factor(x))
```

Comment: Thanks @jay.sf. What does transform do that mutate doesn't?

Comment: @llewmills `transform` is useful for folks that are not able to/don't want to load the `dplyr` package since it comes with R. By the way also `within`, with which you can use the transformed variable instantly in the same call.